# Rails: How to eager load attachments belonging to an associated model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, eager-loading, rails-activestorage

In my Rails v5.2.4.1 app (ruby v2.6.1), I am loading a bunch of messages using a working query. Each message `belongs_to` a `:user` model, and user `has_one_attached :photo`. I am eager loading users with all the messages like this:

```
Message.<query>.includes(:user)
```

Right now, this code `photo.attached? ? photo : 'default_avatar.png'` results in queries like this:

```
SELECT  "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = $1 AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = $2 AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["record_id", 32], ["record_type", "User"], ["name", "photo"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

**How do I eager load `user.photo` and `user.photo.attached?` with my query?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some research, I found the answer to this. I had overlooked it in [the docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.4/classes/ActiveStorage/Attached/Macros.html#method-i-has_one_attached). The problem is solved by using `<association>_attachment` in the includes. So in my question, the eager loading (for `photo`) is done using the following code

```
Message.<query>.includes(user: :photo_attachment)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Message.<query>.includes(user: { photo_attachements: :blob })
```

refrence: [eagerload-active-storage-models](https://blog.saeloun.com/2020/03/06/eagerload-active-storage-models.html)